# Using typeof(self) in Objective-C blocks to declare a strong reference

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Using the `weakSelf/strongSelf` pattern to avoid creating a retain cycle in blocks, this code is pretty common:

```objc
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
void (^block)() = ^{
    typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    // ...more code...
};
```

The question is, does changing the second `typeof(weakSelf)` to `typeof(self)` cause `self` to be captured in the block?

For example:

```objc
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
void (^block)() = ^{
    typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf; // does using typeof(self) here end up capturing self?
    // ...more code...
};
```

If self is not captured, is there any reason to prefer one way or the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't. What Ken said about `typeof` being an compile-time expression does apply.

Also here's a piece of code that proves it:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSObject *o = [NSObject new];

    __weak typeof(o) weakO = o;
    void(^b)() = ^{
      __strong typeof(o) strongO = weakO;
      NSLog(@"o: %@", strongO);
    };

    o = nil;
    b();
    /* outputs:
      2015-05-15 16:52:09.225 Untitled[28092:2051417] o: (null)
     */
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know a way to convert it back to strong? I tried __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf; and it didn't work, it got dealloced because it must still be weak. The reason I ask is I'm not using self, I need it for a block, but as a workaround I can just define the full type.

Answer (score 8):

It shouldn't. If it does, it's a compiler bug.

The `typeof` expression doesn't actually reference the variable `self` or its value. It's strictly a reference to the expression's type, not its value. The expression is strictly a compile-time construct which doesn't survive into the compiled code.

I would prefer `typeof(self)`, personally, but I don't think there's a strong argument to prefer one or the other.

Comment: Not that I don't believe you, but it would be nice to have some evidence to back up what you think.